# IOS - How to get email id list that are synced in with the device?

Tags: ios, swift, email

I want to get the list of email ID's that are synced in with the users device, and just print them. I found one similar question in StackOverFlow, but it is of 5 years old, which is not in Swift.

I'm posting this to get to know whether it is possible or not, So please don't expect code from me. If there is a way to achieve this in IOS, Then please provide me swift 3 code.

I'm using Xcode 8.2, Swift 3.0, IOS 10

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a link to the old question please?

Answer (score 1):

before iOS 9 and older version `ABAddressBook` was available for getting email address of user, But Apple has deprecated this API in iOS 10 and included `CNContactStore`. either you can ask user to input email address or you can show contacts list to choose his/her contact.

Answer (score -1):

If by synced emailIds(Why plural?) you meant the iTunes apple id, then no, its not possible to retrieve that by code in your app.